# What causes Xcode gRPC-C++ Compile Error?

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, cocoapods, dependency-management

I keep on running into a problem while compiling my Xcode IOS app. I'm running into a problem everytime I try to run my app in that I am met with 100 issues from the gRPC-C++ package (see image below). I am not sure how I can fix these issues as I do not even know what gRPC-C++ is (I do not have it installed in my `Podfile`). Additionally, my project is written in swift.

Here is the image with all the errors:
[image]

And here are the contents of my `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

    target 'SPRAIN' do

      use_frameworks!

      # Firebase

      pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
      pod 'Firebase/Database' 
      pod 'FirebaseUI'
      pod 'Fabric'
      pod 'Crashlytics'

      # Other

     pod 'Toast-Swift'
     pod 'SwifterSwift'
     pod 'SwiftRichString'
     pod 'VHProgressBar'
     pod 'SnapKit', '~> 4.0.0'

end
```

As a reference, here are the installed versions of each depency:

```
BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.3)
Crashlytics (3.13.4)
FBSDKCoreKit (5.2.3)
FBSDKLoginKit (5.2.3)
Fabric (1.10.2)
Firebase (6.5.0)
FirebaseAnalytics (6.0.4)
FirebaseAuth (6.2.1)
FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
FirebaseCore (6.1.0)
FirebaseDatabase (6.0.0)
FirebaseFirestore (1.4.2)
FirebaseInstanceID (4.2.2)
FirebaseStorage (3.4.0)
FirebaseUI (8.0.4)
GTMSessionFetcher (1.2.2)
GoogleAppMeasurement (6.0.4)
GoogleSignIn (4.4.0)
GoogleToolboxForMac (2.2.1)
GoogleUtilities (6.2.3)
Protobuf (3.9.0)
SDWebImage (5.0.6)
SnapKit (4.0.1)
SwiftRichString (3.0.1)
SwifterSwift (5.0.0)
Toast-Swift (5.0.0)
VHProgressBar (1.0.2)
gRPC-C++ (0.0.9)
gRPC-Core (1.21.0)
leveldb-library (1.20)
nanopb (0.3.901)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to fix this. Had to entirely remove all remants of cocopods (deleting `pods` directory, `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock` files, as well as `project.xcworkspace`). Uninstalling did not simply work, what seemed to to the trick was deleting `project.xcworkspace`.